# Truncate "Multiple lines of text" column in Sharepoint Online list

Tags: javascript, html, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm stuck on a particular scenario right now because of a recent change by Microsoft in Office 365 regarding the "Multiple lines of text" column in a Sharepoint list.

My main goal is to truncate this column. If this column will have a lot of characters in it, it'll eat up the display page because it can have up to 60k characters.

I'm looking to limit the rows of this column on the list page into like 5rows only  and then add a see more button if possible?

I've found this article about formatting a column in sharepoint list using JSON.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

I've seen that you can put the column into a div using this script but I'm just wondering if I'll be able to limit the rows of this column using JSON?

{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField"
}

Comment: Please upvote to 100 so Microsoft can fix that new feature https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/39710920

Comment: I'm the one who submitted that suggestion though

Answer (score 2):

"Yes" to the limiting to a certain number of lines of text, but "No" to the "see more" button, at least within the capabilities of JSON Formatting.

You can limit the number of lines display with an ellipses ("...") by adding [`line-clamp` CSS styles](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/) to your div. Note the value of `-webkit-line-clamp` is the number of lines you want to display.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "style": {
          "display": "-webkit-box",
          "-webkit-line-clamp": 3,
          "-webkit-box-orient": "vertical",
          "overflow": "hidden"
   },
   "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

However, you cannot embed JavaScript in a JSON column formatter, so if you want a "see more" button that can toggle display the rest of the text, you will need to build a custom-coded [SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Field Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I tried to use the code above but it didn't work, I added a comma right before the "txtContent" because it's invalidated before but it was validated after I added the comma but it seems it still not truncated the column. :(

Comment: Also I noticed that it added a long line of codes on the content of the column: <div class="stufstuff"

Comment: SharePoint has its own css classes that it will inject, but as long as your custom styles `display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  overflow: hidden;` show up, it should get clipped at that number of lines.

Comment: Also note that these styles will not work in Internet Explorer (IE), but will work in Edge, Chrome, and all other "modern" browsers.

Comment: Yea, but it's not clipping it. :(

Comment: I was using the wrong JSON attribute.  I updated the answer, see if that works better.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I tried the updated code but no changes. :( Still not limiting the numbers of rows of the column. :( Hope I can help debug.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint list View formatting only allows a subset of css. Notice that there are no styles with "-webkit-" prefix. Refer to the documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#style

View formatting [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#operators) should be enough. You'll have to ensure that the Multi-line field is configured as a plain text or rich but not enhanced (View formatting doesn't support this yet). I have used the below expression against Multi-line plain text field.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=substring(@currentField, 0, 140) + '...'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stuck with huge custom controls, inject JS, etc
figure out that for me this fulfill my needs with small effort

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "style": {
          "display": "-webkit-box",
          "overflow": "auto",
          "max-height":"2em"
   },
   "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

row is small enough, value isn't lost, and I can scroll or select all and paste somewhere to read all

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if i'm opening back an old thread but this is the closest to what i am looking for.
I have a column that contains multiline data and I am trying to keep only the first line visible and hide the rest so I can have a nice displayed list with minimum gap between the lines. Ideally a JSON script to customize the column formatting.
I tried to keep only a certain number of characters visible, works but then again the problem is that when you open the record, the information in that multiline field is not showing but only the number of characters we limited to be displayed in the first place.

I was thinking about putting the value of the first line in a different column (single line text) and have the rest in a different column, that i can just hide. but when i hide that column, i am not able to use my power automate flow as it detects that it is not available (...) if i can get that to work then my problem is resolved.

Appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: You've asked a question in the answer segment. Please post a new question instead. There you can give a link to this question which will help the readers to get full context.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32046787)